# Trustless deterministic fingerprint of additive subgroup of $GF(2^n)$

Tags: finite-field, integrity, accumulators, homomorphic-signatures

Suppose I have $k$ blocks $B_i$ each consisting of $n$ bits. For erasure code purposes I'd like to be able to produce a computationally binding deterministic hash/fingerprint/digest $H$ such that $\mathrm{verify(x, H)}$ succeeds if $x$ is an additive combination of arbitrary $B_i$ (in $GF(2^n)$), and if not it succeeds with negligible probability. It is ok if there's some additional non-interactive proof token $t$ that's required for $\mathrm{verify}(B_i, H)$ that can be computed using $B_i$, as long as we can compute the token required for $x_1 \oplus x_2$ using some function $\mathrm{merge}(t_1, t_2)$. Unlike most commitment schemes, **I do not care about hiding $B_i$, only computationally binding to it using $H$.**

I want the fingerprint computation to be deterministic, so that by acquiring $H$ *anyone* that has all $B_i$ can provably provide me with some or all, even if the person that originally computed $H$ never communicated with the distributor. $H$ is also important for announcing that you have said data (think content-addressable storage).

It seems a bit silly, but to illustrate what I'm ideally looking for, for $k = 1$ a collision resistant hash digest suffices.

*Linearly Homomorphic Signatures over Binary Fields and New Tools for Lattice-Based Signatures* by Boneh and Freeman almost solves the above problem, where $H$ is the public key and the proof tokens are the signatures on blocks $B_i$. However where it fails is the requirement of a private key, as this must remain secret for $\mathrm{verify}$ to be secure, which means two different (non-communicating) people can't deterministically produce the same $H$.

*On-the-Fly Verification of Rateless Erasure Codes for Efficient Content Distribution* by Krohn et. al. solves the above problem but in $\mathbb{F}_p$ by computing

$$H = \prod_{i=1}^n g_i^{B_i} \bmod p$$

where $g_i$ is a series of generators in $\mathbb{F}_p$ generated in such a way that no one knows $g_i^a \equiv g_j^b \mod p$. Here $\mathrm{merge(t_1, t_2)} = t_1t_2 \bmod p$.

Is there a secure solution over $GF(2^n)$, ideally with small $n$?

Comment: assuming the $p$ in the other solution has to be large for security, I would not expect a $GF(2^n)$ based solution to be secure for small $n.$

Comment: @kodlu Neither would I, with the same scheme. But that is just one scheme.